# CSS: Force child to use parent (table-cell) height

Tags: html, css, height, sticky-footer, css-tables

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#header-wrap,
#content-wrap,
#footer-wrap {
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
}
#content-wrap {
    height: auto;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header-wrap"></div>
    <div id="content-wrap">
        <section id="content"></section>
    </div>
    <div id="header-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

`#wrapper` acts as a table where `#header-wrap`, `#content-wrap` and `#footer-wrap` are tabel cells that help push the footer to the bottom of the page.

**How can I get section** `#content` **to fill** `#content-wrap`**'s height?**

I will not use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Since `#content-wrap` has the browser determine the height, all you should have to do is set `#content` to 100% of the height of the parent element.

```
#content{
    height:100%;
}
```

If it's not getting set to that height, I would guess that there is probably some css property being set later that overrides this one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example...

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet cosectetur...</p>
</div>
```

and the given CSS3 code :

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
div>p {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

When an `absolute` element is set `height` or `width` to 100%, its will match the nearest parent layedout as `relative`or `html` element by default.